# Google CDN for JS - where are the direct paths?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-cdn

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

I don't want to use Google's API key to load the various JS libraries using Google's loader (as the key seems to be tied to a certain domain and I'm trying to write 1 code to work on multiple domains).

In Google's introduction, it says:

> Your application can use our very flexible loader google.load() or
>   direct, path-based access to the scripts.

Where are these "direct, path-based access to the scripts?"

Also, I think I also remember there being a link to get the latest version of a script without having to specify the version number.

Comment: I think it's time you changed your username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them on http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html.  Generally it isn't a good idea to link against latest unless you want to have weird random failures in your application when the version changes and an API you were using changes.

Comment: I must be blind. The link you gave me is exactly the same link I put in my original post. I don't see the direct links. Do you see it?

Comment: E.g. for the jQuery path look at the URL that comes after the word "path:" :) http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: +1stimms. btw i don't blame the op. i have missed it many times. all we look for is a highlighted link. :)

Comment: i SWEAR those paths were NOT there before! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what stimms said. In the link you have provided just look at the path and path(u).
Its not highlighted and thats why you don't see it.

Example

```
jQuery  
   name: jquery  
   latest version: 1.6.2 (view older versions)  
   load request: google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");  
   extras: uncompressed:true (as in google.load("jquery", "1.6.2", {uncompressed:true});  
   path: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js  
   path(u): https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js  
   site: http://jquery.com/  
   note: 1.2.5 and 1.2.4 are not hosted due to their short and unstable lives in the wild...
```

Also for fetching the latest versions, you could do this.

```
  // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",  
  //  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the   
  //  latest version matching that partial revision pattern   
  //  (e.g. 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today and 1 would load 1.6.2)
```

Try these links

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.js

And also please link like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Reason for using protocol-*less* reference: [Cripple the Google CDN’s caching with a single character](http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/)